# D3 labels issue in zoomable scatter plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is the [problem](https://jsfiddle.net/hzey9yv8/) I got. When you drag or zoom in, the labels are not moving

The error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

which corresponds to the last line.

```
  function zoom() {
    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);

    svg.selectAll(".dot")
        .attr("transform", transform);

    svg.selectAll("text")
        .attr("transform", transform);
  }

  function transform(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")";
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this...

```
svg.selectAll("text")
```

... you're selecting **all** the text elements in that SVG, and some of those texts have no bound data.

Solution: give them a class (for instance, `.text`) and select by that class:

```
svg.selectAll(".text")
    .attr("transform", transform);
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zoy0cxwq/